# how to make a asp.net mvc webserver use socket

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sockets

I have an asp.net MVC project,but I don't want to run it on IIS,so I begin to make a webserver myself.

I have finished the 'Receive' Part，'ProcessRequest' is to be continued.

if the request is refer to a file(HTML,jpg,rar...etc), just read file content, return it. if not, the run the asp.net MVC project to get a response. so my question is : how to the run the asp.net MVC project.

```
        public static void Startup()
        {
            var ip = IPAddress.Any;
            var point = new IPEndPoint(ip, 2333);

            var server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Bind(point);
            server.Listen(10);

            server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptClient), server);
        }

        public static void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var server = result.AsyncState as Socket;
            var client = default(Socket);

            try
            {
                client = server.EndAccept(result);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }

            client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessage), client);

            server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptClient), server);
        }

        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        private static void ReceiveMessage(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var client = result.AsyncState as Socket;
            var length = client.EndReceive(result);
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);

            var response = ProcessRequest(message);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            {
                client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
            }

            client.Close();
        }
```

Comment: First spend a few hours on http://asp.net to read about all the (new) hosting options.